# Get last node in Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to access location details from the last added node in Firebase database. You can see on the image below. Its giving error. Please tell me where to correct.

[image]

Here is my code

```
DatabaseReference dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query lastQuery = dbReference.child("User").child("Location").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);

            lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    LatLng prevloc = new LatLng(
                            dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class),
                            dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class)); 

                  }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

Here is error

```
03-21 18:32:10.328 1093-1093/com.jkweblander.mapviewex E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'dalvik.system.DelegateLastClassLoader', referenced from method ab.b
03-21 18:32:14.068 1093-1093/com.jkweblander.mapviewex E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jkweblander.mapviewex, PID: 1093
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jkweblander.mapviewex.MapsActivity$2.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:240)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:183)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query lastQuery = dbReference.child("User").child("Location").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double lat = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            double lng = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            LatLng prevloc = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            Log.d(TAG, lat + ", " + lng);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
});
```

See, I have used the `getChildren()` method to iterate through the `DataSnapshot` object. The result in your logcat will be all latitudes and longitudes of your items within the `Location` node. So even if there is a single object in your `DataSnapshot` object you should iterate in order to get it.

Comment: Yaa I tried to do it but my reputation is less than 15 thats why unable to vote but when It will be greater than 15,I will definately do it